# Vertically center a carousel inside a section

Tags: html, css, carousel, vertical-alignment, flickity

I have a really basic Flickity carousel with some images. My problem is it reamins on the top of the page and I want to center the whole carousel vertically inside my section. My section height is equal to my device's height, so its basically a fullscreen. I tried so many things but I dont know how to solve it. I tried to apply `display:flex;` and `align-items:center;` trick on my section but then it destroys the whole carousel...

My code:

````css
**style.css** ```
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #0b1320;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  background: #0b1320;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  /* flex-box, center image in cell */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* dim unselected */
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s, transform 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
}


/* brighten selected image */

.carousel-cell.is-selected img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-cell {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .carousel-cell {
    width: 60%;
  }
}


/* buttons, no circle */

.flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* arrow color */

.flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
  fill: white;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
  color: white;
}


/* closer to edge */

.flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  left: 0;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  right: 0;
}


/* hide disabled button */

.flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
  display: none;
}
````

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2.2.1/dist/flickity.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Flickity HTML init -->
  <section id="section-b">
    <div class="carousel js-flickity">
      <!-- images from unsplash.com -->
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg" alt="..." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2.2.1/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**Links to flickity.css and flickity.js**

*js:* https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js

*css:* https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `section` block is aligned properly, while `div.carousel` is not.

I've solved the problem, using additional wrapper element - `div.center-wrap`.
Also style was changed:

```css
.carousel {
  background: #0b1320;
  width: 100%;
}
div.center-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Full code snippet:

````css
**style.css** ```
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #0b1320;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  background: #0b1320;
  width: 100%;
}

div.center-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  /* flex-box, center image in cell */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* dim unselected */
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s, transform 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
}


/* brighten selected image */

.carousel-cell.is-selected img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-cell {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .carousel-cell {
    width: 60%;
  }
}


/* buttons, no circle */

.flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* arrow color */

.flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
  fill: white;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
  color: white;
}


/* closer to edge */

.flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  left: 0;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  right: 0;
}


/* hide disabled button */

.flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
  display: none;
}
````

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2.2.1/dist/flickity.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Flickity HTML init -->
  <section id="section-b">
    <div class="center-wrap">

      <div class="carousel js-flickity">
        <!-- images from unsplash.com -->
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg" alt="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" alt="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg" alt="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg" alt="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg" alt="..." />
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2.2.1/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```